# C# ошибка Generic failure при TakeOffline / BringOnline ресурса кластера

Tags: c#, wmi

При попытке выполнить `TakeOffline` или `BringOnline` у ресурса кластера получаю следующую ошибку:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Generic failure 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
```

При этом ресурс успешно останавливается или запускается.

**ClusterManager**

```
public class ClusterManager
{
    private readonly string ClusterName;
    private readonly string ClusterNamespace;
    private ManagementScope Scope;
    private readonly ConnectionOptions Options;

    public ClusterManager(string clusterName, string clusterNameSpace, string user, string password)
    {
        ClusterName = clusterName;
        ClusterNamespace = clusterNameSpace;

        EnvironmentManager env = EnvironmentManager.Instance();

        Options = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
            Username = env.UserName,
            Password = env.Password
        };
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        Scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{ClusterName}\root\{ClusterNamespace}", Options);
        Scope.Connect();
    }

    public ManagementObject GetResource(string name)
    {
        string wmiClassName = "MSCluster_Resource";

        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(Scope, new ManagementPath(wmiClassName), null);
        managementClass.Get();
        ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = managementClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject obj in objectCollection)
        {
            ManagementObject resource = (ManagementObject)obj;

            if (resource["Name"].ToString() == name)
            {
                return resource;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<ManagementObject> GetClusterNodes()
    {
        List<ManagementObject> list = new List<ManagementObject>();

        string wmiClassName = "MSCluster_Node";

        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(Scope, new ManagementPath(wmiClassName), null);
        managementClass.Get();
        ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = managementClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject obj in objectCollection)
        {
            list.Add((ManagementObject)obj);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void TakeOffline(ManagementObject resource)
    {
        try
        {
            resource.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ошибка здесь
            LogManager.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void BringOnline(ManagementObject resource)
    {
        try
        {
            resource.InvokeMethod("Bringonline", null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ошибка здесь
            LogManager.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть уточнили, о каком кластере речь.

Comment: Кстати, вопрос тут больше про WMI чем про C#.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну про WMI, так про WMI. Про кластер - какой он? хз, обычный Failover Cluster

Comment: не бывает обычного failover cluster

Comment: Раз это исключение, то делайте try/catch и смотрите в деталях исключения причину.

Comment: Это и есть ошибка из exception

Comment: Пробовали WMIDiag?